# delete element inside pointers array (resize)

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Im trying to understand pointers, below my code:

```
int main()
{

    int size = 5; //Size of array
    int position = 2; //Position to delete

    int *pointer = new int[size]; //Pointer declaration

    //Populates array with numbers starting at 1 up to size elements (5 in this case)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        pointer[i] = i+1;
    }

    //Prints existing elements (numbers 1 to 5 in this case)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pointer[i] << ", ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I know that if I do `delete [] pointers;` it will delete the array from the memory, but how can I delete just the object inside position 2 or resize the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do either of those things. You can move items around within your existing allocation, and you can make a new allocation, copy items over, and delete the old allocation.

To work with data you should use a container called `vector` which provides member functions to remove an element or resize.  A vector is the equivalent in C++ of what most other languages call an "array".

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I know how to do it with vectors, i was just trying to "resize" the pointer array without copying the elements that i don't want to delete to a new allocation and then deleting the old allocation (this is the way vectors do it if i am not mistaken).

Comment: Apparently that is the only way you can do it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, vectors do that. However vectors also allocate more than you're currently using (called the `capacity`), and remember how many items are in use via `size`. So if you are resizing by a small amount it does not need to do another allocation.